# How to insert variable inside nth-shild(' ') selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need insert variable inside `nth-child()`

```
var slider_wraper = $('.img-slide-wrapper');
var increment = 1;

$('.ar-right').on('click', function(){
    slider_wraper.children('img:nth-child(" + increment + ")').clone().hide().appendTo(img_div).fadeIn(1000);
    increment++;
    console.log(increment);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.children()` expects a string. You start the string with single quotes `'` so when you concatenate you need to use single quotes again, like so

```
...('img:nth-child(' + increment + ')')...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not handled the quotes correctly while using the variable to construct the selector. use:

```
 slider_wraper.children('img:nth-child(' + increment + ')').clone().hide().appendTo(img_div).fadeIn(1000);
                                     //^---------------^ use single quotes instead of double quotes for concatenation
```

or

```
 slider_wraper.children("img:nth-child(" + increment + ")").clone().hide().appendTo(img_div).fadeIn(1000);
```